# Swift 4: scrollViewDidScroll not working

Tags: swift, swift4

1. I created first View controller "MainViewController" and put into it Container View with outlet **contentContainer**.
2. I created second View Controller "AboutContentViewController" and put into it ScrollView
3. I connect Container View and AboutContentViewController programmatically:

```js
class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var contentContainer: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let contentControllerName = "AboutContentViewController"
        if let contentController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: contentControllerName) {
            contentContainer.addSubview(contentController.view)
        }
    }
}
```

4. I tried to catch scrollViewDidScroll event using this code

```js
class AboutContentViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var topGalleryScrollView: UIScrollView!
       
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        topGalleryScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 3750.0, height: 417.0)
        topGalleryScrollView.delegate = self
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        print("scrollViewDidScroll called")
    }
}
```

In this context scrollViewDidScroll event not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved problem. AboutContentViewController is need to be add as child view controller to MainVewController before adding its's view to container:

```js
class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var contentContainer: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let contentControllerName = "AboutContentViewController"
        if let contentController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: contentControllerName) {
            addChildViewController(contentController)
            contentContainer.addSubview(contentController.view)
        }
    }
}
```